# Routes: controller doesn't get called

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, ng-view, ng-controller

I have three files:

- index.html
- players.html
- app.js

**index.html:** pretty simple.

```
<body>   
    <main ng-view></main>
</body>
```

**players.html:** which should display a list of players.

```
<section>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="player in players">
            <h4>{{player}}</h4>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

**app.js:** which contains a *route* to `/players` and *controller* that has a list of players to be displayed on the view.

```
// Module
const myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']); 

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', $routeProvider => { 
    $routeProvider
        .when('/players', {
            controller: 'playersController', 
            templateUrl: 'views/players.html'
        })
}]);

// Controller
myApp.controller('playersController', ['$scope', $scope => {
    $scope.players = ['Kaka', 'Maldini', 'Nesta'];
}]);
```

When I route to '/players', the controller doesn't get called and nothing displays, however when I use `ng-include` instead and add the controller as an attribute, it works fine.

Comment: Clarify: _When I route to 'players.html'_ please. I hope you mean when you route to `/players`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, yes I will edit it

Comment: check https://plnkr.co/edit/Zzg9t3ksuoqM6JmV3GGO?p=preview. Its working. Share some more code. check spelling of `href="#players"`

Comment: Hey @RandyCasburn, 
I applied what you said about the arrow function and it worked, but sorry I didn't get the chance to let you know .. 
Thanks very much for your help . This issue took me long that I felt frustrated

Comment: @ShashankVivek Thank you for letting me know about this very useful site 'Plunker'. 
I checked your code, and figured out that the difference is in the version. It seems that I'm using an older one that doesn't support arrow functions.

Comment: @MoaazBhnas cool, glad to help you mate! :)